# Intl.NumberFormat style currency doesn't work for Chile

Tags: javascript, intl

I'm trying to use this for spanish Chile but I found it doesn't work. But it works for Argentina and Mexico. I would like to know if there is something missing or it is a known issue.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat

My test:

```js
var number = 123456.789;
var number2 = 123456;

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('es-AR', {currency: 'ARS', style: 'currency'}).format(number));
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('es-CL', {currency: 'CLP', style: 'currency'}).format(number2));
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: similar to ARG: $ 123.456

Comment: `$` symbol is output at Firefox. Have you filed a bug for Chromium/Chrome?

Comment: Good catch, I didn't realize it was a browser issue! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It is a Chrome issue, currently it doesn't work properly for all country+currency codes.